# Let $(E,\|\cdot \|_E)$ a normed vector space of finite dimension. Then $\bar B(0,1)=\{x\in E\mid \|x\|\leq 1 \}$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $(E,\|\cdot \|_E)$ a normed vector space of finite dimension. Then $\bar B(0,1)=\{x\in E\mid \|x\|_E\leq 1 \}$ is closed.

The proof looks strange : they say that all norm $\mathcal N$ is continuous $(E,\|\cdot \|_\infty )\to (\mathbb R,|\cdot |)$. Set $\mathcal N(x)=\|x\|_E$. Since $$\bar B(0,1)=\mathcal N^{-1}([0,1]),$$
and $\mathcal N$ continuous, it follow that $\bar B(0,1)$ is closed.

**Question : This argument prove that $\bar B(0,1)$ is closed in $(E,\|\cdot \|_\infty )$, not in $(E,\|\cdot \|_E)$, no ? The argument as written is not totally correct, right ?**

Comment: The norm is continuous as a mapping from $(E, || \cdot ||_{E}) \to (\mathbb{R}, | \cdot |)$. It was probably a typo. It follows from the inequality $| ||x|| - ||y|| | \leq || x-y||$.

Comment: All norm induced topologies are equivalent for finite dimensonal spaces (at least for $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: @NikPronko: Indeed, but I'm talking about the argument as written (so indeed using norm equivalence one can conclude, but this need an other argument). So as written, it's no correct, you agree ?

Comment: @MatijaSreckovic: Yes, I corrected the typo. I don't understand what you did after.

Comment: The argrument is actually correct, but has a wierd wording.  See the answer below.

Comment: I meant, the proof that looks strange to you probably contains a typo: it should be: the norm is continuous as a mapping from $(E, || \cdot ||_{E}) \to (\mathbb{R}, | \cdot |)$ (what the proof said is also correct, but (kind of) irrelevant to the rest of the proof). The inequality I listed proves directly that the norm, as a mapping $(E, || \cdot ||_{E}) \to (\mathbb{R}, | \cdot |)$ is continuous: for any $\varepsilon > 0$, let $\delta = \varepsilon$, and then if $||x-y||_{E} < \delta$, then $| ||x||_{E} - ||y||_{E} | \leq || x-y||_{E} < \delta = \varepsilon$.

Comment: @MatijaSreckovic: Oh yes ! Great, thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Over a finite dimensional real vector space, all norms are equivalent. Therefore, if your set is closed in $(E,\|\cdot\|_\infty)$, then it is also closed in $(E,\|\cdot\|_E)$. Having said this, I must add that I don't see why the author of that proof felt the need of dealing with the norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$.